# extension for Optional Task

Tags: swift, async-await, option-type

Can we make an extension of Optional type where wrapped type is async Task which is generic struct itself? I al so need to use **Task underlying types** inside.

Example of what I need (which is not working itself of course).
Need such parametrised extension, not just generic method inside clean Optional extension. Bottom example produces error `"Cannot find type 'E' in scope"`.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Task<T, E> {

}
```

**UPD:**

I've tried to use the next solution but then I can't get the underlying type of wrapped Task to construct methods. It produces error: `'Success' is not a member type of type 'Wrapped'`.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Task<Sendable, Error> {
    func value(or operation: @escaping @Sendable () async -> Wrapped.Success) async throws {
        let task: Task<Wrapped.Success, Wrapped.Failure>
    }
}
```

**UPD: More concrete example**

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Task<Sendable, Error> {
    func value<Success: Sendable>(or operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success) async throws -> Success {
        let task: Task<Success, Error>
        switch self {
        case let .some(runningTask): task = runningTask //Cannot assign value of type 'Task<any Sendable, any Error>' to type 'Task<Success, any Error>'
        case .none:
            task = Task {
                return try await operation()
            }
        }
        return try await task.value
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of the linked answer (the solution is the same; move the `where` to the `func` rather than the `extension`). Please reply here if you believe there's a difference in this question. (There was no way for you to know this was a duplicate; you really need to know the answer to know what to search for.)

Comment: Questions are different, can you undo deletion?
I need only clear extension as described, not just generic func.
Task is frozen struct, so please bring the question back. Thanks

Comment: The fact that it’s frozen doesn’t matter. Did you try the linked answer? That’s the syntax for this kind of extension. The syntax you’re asking for doesn’t exist. If you can edit your answer to include in what way the linked answer doesn’t work, I’ll reopen, but I tested it before closing this. It seems to work fine for your code.

Comment: `extension Optional { func value<Success: Sendable>(or operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success) async throws -> Success where Wrapped == Task<Success, Error> { ... } }`

Comment: Perfect, I totally forgot about this approach, thank you Rob! Please add this answer to my question and reopen it. It may be helpful to many others. Your answer would be a correct answer here, I wish to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension `where` clauses cannot introduce new type parameters. This is just a current limitation of Swift syntax, and may be improved in the future. But it is always fixable by attaching the `where` clause to each method, which *can* introduce new type variables.

```
extension Optional { 
    func value<Success: Sendable>(or operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success) async throws -> Success 
    where Wrapped == Task<Success, Error> // <===
    { 
        ... 
    } 
}
```

If there are many methods with the same `where` clause this is slightly tedious, but it is always equivalent to putting it on the extension.